# End of file reached. Error 38 in SQL. Passes verification checks

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, c#, corruption

Having issues restoring a database in SSMS, error 38.

The databases are transferred up to google via their Drive API.

Download it on my side and has error.

If I transfer it through teamviewer from client PC I still get the same error.

Only happening on two clients the rest are fine.

I have tried backing up with `FORMAT` options and `WITH CHECKSUM`. Both succeed and backup is taking when verifying.

I have ran `restore fileheaders` only and get proper data except the `physicalname` path has a lowercase 'c' for the drive on the problem databases.

I have read this could be a corrupt database but I don't understand how the checksum and verify sql functions pass if so. Any insight would really help.

This is the backup command used in C#

```
"BACKUP DATABASE " + database + " TO DISK = '" 
+ database + "_" + dateTime.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH") + 
"_CloudBackup.bak' WITH NAME = 'database', INIT, CHECKSUM"
```

EDIT: Running `dbcc check` on the database produced no errors. I have tried updated the physical name of the .mdf and .ldf it does not work still. Taking a backup from SSMS produces a valid backup file. It has something to do with the services I wrote.

EDIT 2: I am restoring through SSMS GUI. I have also tried `RESTORE DATABASE db_name FROM 'backup_path'`

Commands

`RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'backup_path'`

On both computers, mine and the server PC yields "The backup set on file 1 is valid."

`RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'backup_path'`

Have only test on my PC. Returns paths to mdf and ldf, no errors.

Both PCs have sql server 2012 (SP1)

Comment: Try running [`CHECKDB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on the source server.

Comment: @Alex I will try this when the clients get in today. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Alex I have tried running checkdb and it produced no errors. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @AustenSwanson You don't show the code you're using to restore the database. If you load up SSMS on the "problem" server, or **another server**, and execute `RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK='<Your backup name here>.bak'` do you still get the same error? Also, are the backup and restore servers running the exact same version of SQL Server?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for the response. I added another edit to clarify some of your questions.

Comment: I read a post that mentioned deduplication could be causing this problem.  You may want to try backing the database up with compression (just append the word ", COMPRESSION" at the end of your backup command after the word "CHECKSUM".  This may prevent any deduplication from occurring if that is the issue.

Comment: Yes, @Alf47 is right, I was going to suggest the same thing next.

Comment: @Alf47, I will try this sometime this week from the clients PC, at their mercy for access. I will post back with the results. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @Alf47, I tried using compression but SQL server express won't allow it as it is not a feature in express versions. On a side note, I removed all compression all together (zipping the .bak via ZipArchive library in .NET) and pass it up to google and it works fine now. Something must be going wrong in the compression. Thank you for the lead into looking at compression =)

Answer (score 0):

> I removed all compression all together (zipping the .bak via ZipArchive library in .NET) and pass it up to google and it works fine now. Something must be going wrong in the compression. Thank you for the lead into looking at compression =)

Originally left in a comment by user [Austen Swanson](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/186196/austen-swanson) (the OP).

So rather than the database being corrupt, the *backup* was getting corrupted in the process of trying to compress (or decompress) it using third-party compression.